# Center logo and fill 4 images to page?

Tags: html, css

i would like to have my logo centred to the four images. How do i do this? i would like the four images to fill the window and the logo to centre to them. I also don't want to stretch the images but would consider resizing them if needs be

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #466995;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

li:hover {
  color: #DBE9EE;
}


body {
  margin: 0;

}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#container {
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.containermenu {

}

.containermenu img{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 40%;
  right: 40%;



}

#process img {
  width: 100%;
}

#process {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://oi68.tinypic.com/2njh9id.jpg"></a></div>
  <div class="containermenu"><a href="packaging.html"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></a></div>
  <div class="containermenu"><a href="photography.html"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></a></div>
  <div class="containermenu"><a href="illustration.html"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></a></div>
  <div class="containermenu"><a href="about.html"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/SteveBarrett/pen/YpErop)

Comment: Please create meaningful question headers. "Any idea guys?" doesn't tell anyone what the question is about.

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry, title has been changed

Comment: Please edit your text.

Answer (score 0):

To center an item perfectly in the page use the following CSS

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

EDIT: [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/Havock94/pen/YpEEEr)

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any way i can stick the logo in the centre of the four images?

Comment: Check my link again. I've added a position: absolute to the #container as well to make it centered too

Comment: Feel free to upvote and mark as selected answer to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` to center in css [More infor here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #466995;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
ul {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 100px;
}
li:hover {
  color: #DBE9EE;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#container {
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.containermenu {} .containermenu img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#logo {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute; /*fixed*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#process img {
  width: 100%;
}
#process {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="http://oi68.tinypic.com/2njh9id.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <a href="packaging.html">
      <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <a href="photography.html">
      <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <a href="illustration.html">
      <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <a href="about.html">
      <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```